# Is there a way of replacing null values with a subtotal in Power Query?

Tags: powerquery, m

For example, if I have a table that looks like this:

| Group | Subgroup | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Subgroup 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Subgroup 2 | 2 |
| 1 | Subgroup 3 | 3 |
| 1 | Subtotal | null |
| 2 | Subgroup 1 | 3 |
| 2 | Subgroup 2 | 5 |
| 2 | Subgroup 3 | 6 |
| 2 | Subgroup 4 | 2 |
| 2 | Subtotal | null |
| 3 | Subgroup 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Subtotal | null |
| 4 | Subgroup 1 | 3 |
| 4 | Subgroup 2 | 4 |
| 4 | Subgroup 3 | 5 |
| 4 | Subtotal | null |

How can I transform it into this:

| Group | Subgroup | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Subgroup 1 | 1 |
| 1 | Subgroup 2 | 2 |
| 1 | Subgroup 3 | 3 |
| 1 | Subtotal | **6** |
| 2 | Subgroup 1 | 3 |
| 2 | Subgroup 2 | 5 |
| 2 | Subgroup 3 | 6 |
| 2 | Subgroup 4 | 2 |
| 2 | Subtotal | **16** |
| 3 | Subgroup 1 | 2 |
| 3 | Subtotal | **2** |
| 4 | Subgroup 1 | 3 |
| 4 | Subgroup 2 | 4 |
| 4 | Subgroup 3 | 5 |
| 4 | Subtotal | **12** |

Every Subtotal line has at least one Subgroup line above it; there are no consecutive Subtotal lines.

Answer (score 0):

ClLick select Group and right click to Group By...

Do operation Sum on Values column and name the column Values

Add column custom column Subgroup with ="Subtotal" as the formula

Combine the new table with the old table then remove the null rows

Resort

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Group", Int64.Type}, {"Subgroup", type text}, {"Values", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Group"}, {{"Values", each List.Sum([Values]), type number}}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Subgroup", each "Subtotal"),
Custom = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Values] <> null)) & #"Added Custom",
#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(Custom,{{"Group", Order.Ascending}, {"Subgroup", Order.Ascending}}) 
in #"Sorted Rows"
```